# gulp.js+browserify: Dynamically generate development-specific files

Tags: node.js, gulp, browserify

I have an application that has some development-specific debugging code in it. Currently, all development code is guarded by a variable called `dev` at the top of the file. Here's an example of what my app does:

```
var dev = true;

if (dev) {
  console.log("Hello developer");
} else {
  console.log("Hello production");
}
```

When I go to deploy my application, I have to manually change the dev variable form true to false. This sucks.

I'm in the middle of migrating from hand-rolled builds to gulp.js and I want to solve this development vs. production build problem cleanly. I'm thinking about the following:

```
// Inside main.js
var dev = require('./isdev');
if (dev) //...

// Inside isdev.js:
module.exports = true;
```

Now, when I build for production, instead of manually setting the dev flag to `false`, I want to replace isdev.js from `module.exports = true;` to `module.exports = false;`. My specific question is, **how do I automate gulp such that `gulp development` produces a file with `dev = true` and `gulp production` produces a file with `dev = false`.**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's an update to those who are curious.

First, I have an `options.js`:

```
exports.dev = false;
```

I also have a `options_dev.js`:

```
exports.dev = true;
```

Inside of `gulpfile.js`, I have the following code that parses input arguments:

```
// Parse the arguments. Use `gulp --prod` to build a production extension
var argv = parseArgs(process.argv.slice(2));
var dev = !argv['prod'];  // Whether to build a development extension or not
```

Finally, when I pipe to browserify, I have the following:

```
var resolve = require('browser-resolve');
// ...
.pipe(browserify({
  debug: dev,
  resolve: function(pkg, opts) {
    // Replace options.js with options_dev.js if this is a dev build
    if (dev) {
      opts.modules['./options'] = 'src/options_dev.js';
    }
    return resolve.apply(this, arguments);
  }
}))
```

The magic happens by using a custom resolve function, dynamically swapping `./options` with `options_dev` for development builds. The browserify docs say:

> You can give browserify a custom opts.resolve() function or by default it uses browser-resolve.

When we run `gulp`, we build a development version. When we run `gulp --prod`, we build a production version. The value of `require('./options').dev` allows us to dynamically change things like server endpoints, etc. Cool!

Comment: You should try not to include development code in your production app. So instead of including a true/false flag, try including a development URL or production URL and try including development code VS production code. You'll need a slightly more complex way of designating files for dev/prod, maybe they reside in different folders or you could make a browserify transform. However you do it, your app will be lighter, load faster and a lot more secure and it'll be worth it! :)

Comment: when is `reslove` called? I tried this code but that resolve function never runs.

Answer (score 2):

The way that I've seen this done is to set the environment variable on the command line before the execution command.  An example of doing this with the Node.JS CLI (in a bash-like environment) would be:

```
ENV=dev node

> process.env.ENV
'dev'
```

Then in your code, you could do:

```
var dev = process.env.ENV === 'dev'
```

So with gulp, you could use:

```
ENV=dev gulp <task name>
```

I tested this out with the following snippet, and it works:

```
gulp.task('dev', function(){
  if (process.env.ENV === 'dev')
    console.log("IT WORKED");
  else
    console.log("NO DICE");
});
```

**Edit:**

You can write out the environment to the file `isdev` right before building:

```
var fs = require('fs');
gulp.task('build', function(){
  if (process.env.ENV === 'dev')
    fs.writeFileSync('isdev', 'module.exports = true');
  else
    fs.writeFileSync('isdev', 'module.exports = false');

  // kick off build
});
```

Now, the correct value will be present in `isdev` for any `require` call in the built bundle.  You could extend this to other specified environments as well (or to other configuration flags).

Comment: This is a great starting point but I really need to go one step further. Based on this new dev environment flag, how can I selectively embed content such that `require('./isdev')` in my sources returns true when the dev flag is set and false when it is not.

Comment: why do you even need the /isdev file to begin with?